# mapping an xml response to class?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I don't know how to represent some XML as a C# class. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to properly map this xml? Here's my attempt below:

```
<authenticationResponse>
  <Accounts>
    <AccountId>1</AccountId>
    <AccountId>5</AccountId>
  </Accounts>
</authenticationResponse>


public class authenticationResponse
{
    [XmlElement("Accounts")]
    [DataMember]
    public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public long id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So, what problem are you having?

Comment: I am reading from a REST endpoint using Microsoft's Webapi. The xml coming back is properly filled with accountids, but the List is null in my object.

Comment: Show the full XML, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may load this data via LINQ to XML:

```
XElement x = XElement.Load("YourFile.xml");
List<Account> accounts = x.Element("Accounts")
                            .Elements("AccountId")
                            .Select(e => new Account { id = (long)e })
                            .ToList();
```

In this case `authenticationResponse` class is redundant.

If you've got the response in memory (not in a file on your harddrive), you may use this:

```
string response = ...
XElement x = XElement.Load(new StringReader(response));
```

Comment: If you're loading the XML from a string instead of a file, use `XElement.Parse`.

Comment: This line does not compile: 'Select' is causing problems....  .Select(e => new Account { id = (long)e })

Comment: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user486480 To use this code you should use at least .NetFramework 3.5 (or higher) and add `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Xml.Linq;` to your using list

Comment: @user the following links should be appropriate: [Using LINQ in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655883%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Comment: @user glad to help you! Also the following links should be helpful: [Using LINQ in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655883%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio 2012 has this cool feature called "Paste XML As Classes" (under Edit > Paste Special).  You can simply copy the XML into the clipboard and this "Paste XML As Classes" feature will generate and paste this `authenticationResponse` class for you:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class authenticationResponse
{

    private byte[] accountsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("AccountId", IsNullable = false)]
    public byte[] Accounts
    {
        get
        {
            return this.accountsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.accountsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can deserialize the XML to the following class:

```
[XmlRoot("authenticationResponse")] 
public class AuthenticationResponse 
{ 
    [XmlArrayItem("AccountId")] 
    public List<long> Accounts { get; set; } 
}
```

Here is the code for deserialization:

```
AuthenticationResponse response = null; 
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AuthenticationResponse));

using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml)) 
{ 
    response = (AuthenticationResponse)serializer.Deserialize(sr); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for webapi authResponse =     response.Content.ReadAsAsync<authenticationResponse>().Result;

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Visual Studio 2012 so don't have the Paste XML as Class.  However, in situations like this, if I need a quick solution, I often use the xsd.exe program in the Visual Studio Tools.  It generates a C# class from an XML Schema Definition (.xsd file).

If you don't have an XSD for the XML in question you can quickly generate one from a number of XML tools.  I use oXygen (a trial version is available), load your XML sample and then select Tools | Generate/Convert Schema.  Longer term, assuming you don't want to rely in 3rd party tools, I'd insist the source of the XML data also provided me with a Schema.

Sample xsd.exe command line (run from the Visual Studio Command Prompt):

```
    xsd.exe FileName.xsd /n:Namespace.Cust.App.UI /c
```

will produce a .cs file called FileName.cs.